# Can I search countries by country_code in AdWords API v201109?

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to find Country locations in AdWords API v201109 by country code, as it was possible in previous version of the API. However, in official documentation I can't find a way how to do that.

I can search by LocationName and entering country code. It works for some country codes ("CZ" - Czech Republic), but for some it doesn't ("SK" - Slovakia) - I suspect it doesn't work for most of country codes.

Of course, there's an obvious workaround: fetch Countries appendix and translate country codes to country names or ids locally. But I'd rather just search by country code directly. Is it possible?

Comment: See this link https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/adwords-api/0HmtCDpKyzs

Comment: ...and Danial Klimkin should know, he created ruby gem for Adwords API. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to search countries by country_code only in AdWords API v201109. They havn't given feature for search with country code only. You are good hacky method.

They might develop later that for the same. Keep you code extend-able.

Answer (score 1):

We recently published a CSV files that contains all the targetable locations, with a column for country code:

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/geotargeting